# unable to make edit request through angular

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am making a basic issue tracking tool. I am able to make http request to the back end api which i built.except PUT request, every other request works fine.

When i try to edit a user details. i get the below error message

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://trackerapi.sanjayinfotechy.com/api/v1/user/:userId/edit?authToken=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJqd3RpZCI6IlBQT1ROYTlDbSIsImlhdCI6MTU1Njc4NTEwMjQ1NSwiZXhwIjoxNTU2ODcxNTAyLCJzdWIiOiJhdXRoVG9rZW4iLCJpc3MiOiJlZENoYXQiLCJkYXRhIjp7Im1vYmlsZU51bWJlciI6MTIzNDU2LCJmaXJzdE5hbWUiOiJtdW5uYSIsImxhc3ROYW1lIjoiZGhpbmlsIiwidXNlcklkIjoiZWYybU93aVdzIiwiZG9iIjoiMTk5Ni0wMy0wOFQwMDowMDowMC4wMDBaIiwiY29tcGFueU5hbWUiOiJXZWxscyBGYXJnbyIsInJvbGUiOiJBbmFseXN0IiwiZW1haWwiOiJtdW5uYS5kaGluaWxAZ21haWwuY29tIn19.CUctgYPuZmwsZf3rFTQqTWFOsttBdz6bTZFt7mPxYcY' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

When i try top perform the same put request in postman, i am able to edit the data successfully without any errors. The error occurs only in angular 4 project.

See my code below

http.service.ts file

```
public editUserDetails(authToken, userId, data): Observable<any>{

    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('userId', userId)
      .set('firstName', data.firstName)
      .set('lastName', data.lastName)
      .set('dob', data.dob)
      .set('companyName', data.companyName)
      .set('role', data.role)
      .set('mobileNumber', data.mobileNumber)
      .set('email', data.email)
      .set('password', data.password)

    return this.http.put(`${this.url}/user/:userId/edit?authToken=${authToken}`, params)
  } // end edit user details
```

and this is edit.component.ts file

```
public editFunction: any = () =>{
    let data = {
      firstName: this.currentUser.firstName,
      lastName: this.currentUser.lastName,
      dob: this.currentUser.dob,
      companyName: this.currentUser.companyName,
      role: this.currentUser.role,
      mobileNumber: this.currentUser.mobileNumber,
      email: this.currentUser.email,
    }

    this._http.editUserDetails(this.authToken, this.currentUserId, data).subscribe(
      (apiResponse)=>{
        if(apiResponse.status === 200){
          this.toastr.customToastr('Details Edited Successfully')
          setTimeout(()=>{
            this.router.navigate(['/user-info'])
          }, 1500)
        } else {
          this.toastr.warningToastr(apiResponse.message)
        }
      },
      (err)=>{
        console.log(err)
        this.toastr.errorToastr(`Some Error Occured`)
      }
    )
  } // end edit function
```

code for edit in backend api using nodejs

```
let editUser = (req, res)=>{
    let options = req.body || req.query || req.params
    UserModel.update({userId: req.params.userId || req.body.userId || req.query.userId}, options, {multi: true}, (err, result)=>{
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            logger.error(err.message, 'User Controller: editUser', 10)
            let apiResponse = response.generate(true, 'Failed To Edit User Details', 500, null)
            res.send(apiResponse)
        } else if (check.isEmpty(result)) {
            logger.info('No User Found', 'User Controller: editUser')
            let apiResponse = response.generate(true, 'No User Found', 404, null)
            res.send(apiResponse)
        } else {
            let apiResponse = response.generate(false, 'User Details Edited successfully', 200, result)
            res.send(apiResponse)
        }
    })
} // end edit user
```

please let me know where i am doing the code wrong.

Comment: As the error says, the edit router of your services response without control headers:  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Set your service to provide these headers. You can call this resource from postman because postman ignore the request-origin-policy

Comment: but why am i getting this error only for PUT request. it does not happen with any other requests?

Comment: maybe our API sending other headers for the PUT request ?

Comment: Yes, maybe. But not sure. let me know what i can do here now

Comment: Then check it to be sure. If you PUT with postman, your service should return this header. If it is not present, fix your API to do so.

Comment: I have checked multiple times. i dont see any mistake. I have put the edit api code above. Please let me know if i am doing anything.

Comment: postman is not a browser so a CORS error won't occur

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error that you are getting carefully and you will get the answer:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

This is a CORS issue and not the issue of you code. Read more about CORS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

So the resource (the http API) that you are calling has not been configured for the request origins that it should allow and return response.

The problem is most probably you are making the POST request from a different origin (you can check the origin of your request in chrome developer tool in network tab) and the API is on a different domain and hence you are getting this error.

Ask you API developer to enable the origin from where you are making this request.

Comment: actually i am making a PUT request. other requests work fine. The CORS only happens on PUT request.

Answer (score 0):

Found the Solution. By changing the below code in my routing middleware'

i had written let headers ={ }

i changed it to var headers = { }

I dont know how it impacted. but its working.
If anyone knows the reason. please let me know.

Comment: the headers sent must have been corrected, can't say more without seeing the routing middleware, read Ritesh post (+1) and link to understand CORS